# Laravel entrust 5.2.x class permission not found while seeding

Tags: php, laravel, acl, seeding, entrust

As above the title, I followed the tutorial to create ACL modal in laravel 5.2 , the bug hit as the attached when I was seeding a class for PermissionTableSeeder.

Well, I hope there are people who can help me on this issue.

This is the bug:

[image: BUG]

Answer (score 0):

that error is because of Permission model is not found correctly in your PermissionTableSeeder use permission model with full namespace

add the below use statement at the top of your seeder.

`use App\Permission`

Comment: thx pal, i have added it, but unfortunately, it still found nothing.

Comment: where is your Permission model located? what is namespace of Permission model?

Comment: wow, I just solved it with adding namespace for the modals, but it looks like trigger another error which written "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException" name....